# How to attach a file unto the element. Using fileobject or blobs

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, blob

I want to attach an image src unto the file field so I can upload it in the background. I cant figure out how to attach a file unto the file form field with JavaScript.

**I want to take the src of an image like this one below**

[image]

**and place it here using javascript so I can save it in the background.**

`<input type="file" name="CAT_Custom_7" id="CAT_Custom_7" class="cat_textbox" />`

I read that I can use the file object and blob to do this but I cant figure out where to start. Any pointers will be great

[the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davadi/dro4em8t/)

Answer (score -1):

```
var img = "url('http://www.......')";
document.getElementById("div").style.backgroundImage = img;
document.getElementById("image").src = img;
```

Try this

Comment: `upload it in the background` and `save it in the background` are not referring to a background image but rather a task which happens in the background while other [seemingly more important] things are happening in the foreground.